Is this vertical crack on my foundation a concern?


Is this vertical crack a structural damage? Can I cover the crack with type S mortar?

It's a hairline crack. Seal it with some paint and keep an eye on it. Normally these are nothing to be concerned about.
If it gets bigger, call in a foundation professional. Your insurance company may pay for an inspection and remediation.
